# How do I solve Google Chrome Search Page Layout dysfunction?

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

Today when I open the browser, it is strange because normally the browser should display the search frame and the wallpaper. Is it a dysfunction of the software and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. Some malicious problem set my default search engine as Yahoo. And I switched it back to Google.